# Azure spring boot connection Timeout Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created an application which connects to Azure queue and consumes the message. Issue is after 240000 ms connection is closed automatically and I am getting the exception `"org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.MessageConsumerException: The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 240000 milliseconds and is closed by container`. 
PFB My configuration code to connect to Azure queue.

```
    @Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = null;
    try {
        cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactoryImpl.createFromURL(url));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setClientId(applicationName);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.error("Exception", e);
    }
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public MessageListenerContainer getContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    container.setDestinationName(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(messageConsumer);
    container.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    return container;
}
```

and my pom.xml file

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and my url is: 
`amqps://user:<password>@myqueue2.servicebus.windows.net`

My question is how to keep the connection active or how to reconnect to queue after exception. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Qpid official document about [Failover Configuration options](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.39.0/docs/index.html#failover-configuration-options), please try to use the URI for failover to enable failover feature of Qpid for automatically reconnecting when connection lost.